# Meld background highlighting broken

Tags: debian, gtk, meld

At some point (which I unfortunately didn't note down precisely, but is reasonable to believe that it was after an `apt-get (dist-)upgrade` operation) meld's background highlighting stopped being displayed correctly.

In the following screenshot you can see that the light blue highlighting is missing from the two text panels:

[image: screenshot of user's Meld Merge setup]

Compare e.g. with http://meldmerge.org/ screenshot:

[image: screenshot from Meld Merge website]

I tried to hunt for the problem by reading about Gtk Css (which meld is apparently using) and went as far as checking that my `/usr/share/meld/meld.css` has the right contents, but I have no clue what to do next.

I am running Debian Jessie, GNOME and `$ meld --version` returns `meld 3.12.0`.

I cannot find any menu or command line option to reach a "Preferences" menu in the version that I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in:

```
$ meld --version
meld 3.12.1
```